# Django CBV - set form class based on permissions?

Tags: python, django

I have created two forms in forms.py one form has less fields than the other.

what I would like to now do is get the current users permissions and set the form class of the CBV based on those perms.

below is my current view:

```
class EditCircuit(UpdateView):
    model = Circuits
    # if user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.edit_circuit')))
    form_class = CircuitForm
    # else
    # form_class = CircuitFormRestricted
    template_name = "sites/circuit_form.html"

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.edit_circuit')))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
        self.site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.site_id) 
        return super(EditCircuit, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
        return reverse_lazy("sites:site_detail_circuits", args=(self.site_id,))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.site_data = self.object.site_data
        return super(EditCircuit, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['SiteID']=self.site_id
        context['SiteName']=self.site.location
        context['FormType']='Edit'
        context['active_circuits']='class="active"'

        return context
```

Comment: you mean you don't want any user to edit, just the author?

Comment: I want users to be able to view it but only certain users can edit it, and some form fields will not be visible to the standard user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `get_form_class` method.

```
def get_form_class(self):
    if self.request.user.has_perm('config.edit_circuit'):
        return CircuitForm
    return CircuitFormRestricted
```

Also, it looks as though you don't need the `get_form_kwargs` definition, as it's not doing anything at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own mixin like this

```
class AuthorOnlyMixin(object):
    def has_permissions(self):
        return self.get_object().created_by == self.request.user
```

then use it like this

```
class EditViewClass(AuthorOnlyMixin, EditView):
    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.has_permissions():
            return FormWithPermission
        else:
            return FormWithoutPermission
```